# Is there a hotkey to jump to the beginning or end of a python if statement in Vim?

Tags: vimscript

I use VsCode with the Vim plugin. In other languages using Vim to jump to brackets is good enough, but python if statements don't have brackets.

I have found no Vim plugin or macro for this, is it impossible?

There is this Vim plugin (and its even available in VsCode), but it does not support Python (per the maintainer in a github [issue](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redguardtoo.matchit#:%7E:text=Jump%20between%20matching%20HTML%20tags%2C%20brackets%20and%20other%20items%20in,developer%20using%20JSX%20and%20React.)):

In raw vimscript (which the VsCode Vim plugin has *some* support for) I would need to jump to the next word matching `else:`, but only if its on the same level of indentation as the `if` I'm currently on.

I'm having trouble finding vimscript examples of moving the cursor to a location matching the same indent.

I just want to add I don't always have the luxury of formatting the code, I'm often reading others code. So I can't just always put a blank line between if and else and jump to next blank line or something like that.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you are searching a solution within VsCode or within Vim. Could you clarify?

Comment: Does matchit not work? `:help matchit` perhaps `:let b:match_words = '\<if\>:\<elif\>:\<else\>'` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`?

Comment: Also, the VSCode-specific parts are off-topic; only the Vim-behavior of the plugin is on-topic. I've edited to focus on those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be interested to the [vim-indentwise](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise) plugin.

It allows you to navigate through the code by level of indentation:

- `[-` one level down (e.g. from body of `if` to the `if` condition, from `def` to `class`)
- `[=` same level up (e.g. from `else` to `if`)
- `]=` same level down (e.g. from `if` to `else`)

Comment: Thats probably good enough for me. FYI looks like its eventually going to be added to vscode: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/7667

Comment: Nice :-) But it seems to be on hold for 6 months :-/